# What do I do if a fp marking is in between two notes?

Tags: notation, dynamics

[image]

How can i play the section with forte piano fp where fp is between two notes

Comment: What instrument is this for, or is it sung? Also, your title doesn't match your question.

Comment: @Dekkadeci It's a choral score, SATB.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a result of poor notation. The *fp* shouldn't be in between the D and C, because that would be nonsensical.

Instead, the *fp* should be aligned with either the D or the C. Since the D begins both the musical and the textual phrase, we can pretty safely assume that the *fp* should be shown on the D.

Comment: Asuming the comment above that this is a choral score is correct, I can no longer assume that the fp being between 2 notes is poor notation.